# Warning: file_get_contents(inc-star-rating.php?id=10) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, include, file-get-contents

Heres my code within `functions.php`:

```
<?php

$id = 10;
$html = file_get_contents("inc-star-rating.php?id=$id");

echo $html;

?>
```

Heres the contents of `inc-star-rating.php`:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

echo "<div>I have the ID of $id</div>";

?>
```

They are both in the same directory on my server, so why am I getting the following error?:

> Warning: file_get_contents(inc-star-rating.php?id=10)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory

Comment: Because there is no file called `inc-star-rating.php?id=10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inc-star-rating.php?id=10` is probably not the right file name. It probably does not exist like this in the filesystem.

If you mean to fetch a URL via an HTTP request, you need to explicitly give the **full URL** as it's accessible through the web server:

```
file_get_contents("http://localhost/inc-star-rating.php?id=$id")
```

Whether this is a good idea or not is a different topic though. Usually you want to `require` other PHP files and execute their code by calling functions in them, not make a new HTTP request.

Comment: ... and doing HTTP requests to localhost is almost certainly bad design

Comment: i've tried using fread and it gives the samr result. if its bad design please show me a better solution so i know for future reference.

Comment: @scarhand As I said: `require_once 'inc-star-rating.php';`, then call some code in there. Learn about functions and classes. It doesn't all have to go through `$_GET` parameters.